# DataTables not properly aligning pagination elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am working in DataTables for the first time and I am having some issues with the pagination elements. As you can see from the screenshots below, the buttons are overlapping and I don't see how to resolve this. Please take a look and tell me if you see what's wrong.

[image]

[image]

```
<div id="daily-summary-report-wrapper" class="ui3-table-container">
    <table id="daily-summary-report-table" class="display" style="height: 100% ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10%" scope="col">Date Order</th>
                <th style="width:30%" scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Count</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetSummaryReportTable("", "", true);
    });

    function GetSummaryReportTable(startDate, endDate, isInitPageLoad) {
        $('#daily-summary-report-table').DataTable({
            "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
            "columns": [
                { "name": "Day" },
                { "name": "Date" },
                { "name": "Count" },
                { "name": "TotalPrice" }
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/s8dwp5vu/4/

Comment: Yeah, with this code we can show correctly...